# Add a class to a div when a vimeo embed is playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I want to add a class to a div when a vimeo embed is playing. I found some info on [Vimeo API](http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api). [This is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HfwWY/2557/) i ended up with. It works on the left video, when you play it the tester div turns red, when you pause it it turns yellow. How could i change the code so that it would work for both video's? Or to be more specific, on any number of vimeo embeds?

Just for completeness, heres the code im using:

HTML:

```
<iframe id="player1" 
    src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/27855315?api=1&player_id=player1"
    width="400" height="225" frameborder="0"
    webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen>
</iframe>

<iframe id="player2"
    src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/27855375?api=1&player_id=player2"
    width="400" height="225" frameborder="0"
    webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen>
</iframe>

<p>Video status: <span class="status">...</span></p>
<div id="tester"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#tester{
  background-color:yellow;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

#tester.playing{
  background-color:red;
}
```

JS/jQuery:

```
var iframe = $('#player1')[0],
    player = $f(iframe),
    status = $('.status');

// When the player is ready, add listeners for pause, finish, and playProgress
player.addEvent('ready', function() {
    status.text('ready');

    player.addEvent('pause', onPause);
    player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
    player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
});

// Call the API when a button is pressed
$('button').bind('click', function() {
    player.api($(this).text().toLowerCase());
});

function onPause(id) {
    $('#tester').removeClass('playing');
}

function onFinish(id) {
    $('#tester').removeClass('playing');
}

function onPlayProgress(data, id) {
    $('#tester').addClass('playing');
}
```

**Update:**

Im adding the vimeo's dynamically to an empty iframe. This is where the problem arises of the solution not working anymore. To clarify things ive putted 2 fiddles together.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HfwWY/2564/) works. When you play the video the yellow tester div turns red.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HfwWY/2563/) doesnt work. First click the green "video 1" button, then the player shows. But when you press play on it the yellow tester div doesnt turn red.

I cant figure out what the problem is. When i inspect element, both iframes look exactly the same when they are rendered. Whats the difference and why doenst it work when i load the src dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to all of the player iframes so in the code you just need to check if the player has the class or not and change whatever you want to.

Also it looks like you have to define the players in js as well and bind the event each time. There might be better ways to do this but I just looked at the code and came up with this

http://jsfiddle.net/HfwWY/2558/

```
<iframe id="player1" class="change" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/27855315?api=1&player_id=player1" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
<iframe id="player2" class="change" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/27855375?api=1&player_id=player2" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

JS

```
var iframe = $('.change');

iframe.each( function() {
    var player = $f( $(this)[0] );
    // When the player is ready, add listeners for pause, finish, and playProgress
    player.addEvent('ready', function() {
        status.text('ready');

        player.addEvent('pause', onPause);
        player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
        player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
    });

} );

var status = $('.status');
```

Feel free to change the class change to something more meaningful like videoPlayer or whatever, just make sure the change is applied in js as well

Comment: Thanks, this is in core what i am looking for, and it works great. Although im having great trouble getting it implemented in my own site. Its a little complicated, cause theres a few more things involved. But i cant get my head around why it dont work... Maybe you can take a look? It would be quite some work to get it all in a fiddle, and im not sure if it would make it clearer. [This is the url of my site](http://hetisnieuw.nl/HIGGS/index.html). If you scroll 1 page to the left, and then click the left video, the active nav item should get the class playing, but it doesnt.

Comment: On a sidenote, i also noted that in the fiddle, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HfwWY/2560/) also works.

Comment: I tried looking at your site but I find it hard to do anything on it because the complexity of it. As long as you understand the js in my answer you should be able to figure it out. If you can't get something to work then try defining each video by itself until they all work then try combining it. I couldn't even figure out where the first video is on your page

Comment: and yes adding a new player with the class change will work as well. You can add 40 more with the class change and they will all work.

Comment: i figured that. I tried it in the fiddle. So it should work in my site. Like i said, when you open the site, when you sroll one time to the left with the left white barshaped button, and then click the left video, itll start playing. At that point the active nav item should get the class playing.

Comment: I think the problem might be in this line: `var player = $f( $(this)[0] );` I dont really get what it does/mean, and its the only line in there i can figure out. As far as i can tell every other line should be ok. Could you explain me to me what this line exactly does/means?

Comment: updated my question, including 2 fiddles so you wont have to wrestle through the complexity of my site;) Could you please take a look?

Comment: the `$(this)[0]` is the same thing as your cold where [0] appeared. In this case this refers to the current element. In your original code you had `iframe = $('#player1')[0]` it's the same as that, except your code does it to player1 where my code does it to all of the players in the each loop

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Still i have no clue as to why its not working. Did you take a look at the 2 new fiddles i made?

Comment: it does not work because the video does not exist when you bind the handler. You should leave the video src in as you did before and simply hide the videos using css, and when you click the tabs, just show the correct video http://jsfiddle.net/HfwWY/2565/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The problem is i will need like 200 vimeo embeds in that website, which will MASSIVELY slow down the page load time. That is the reason why i wanna add the src dynamically, then it doesnt affect initial page load. Would there be any way to make this work in the way the other fiddle i made works?

Comment: The problem being that css display:none doesnt stop it from being loaded, as where it being in a function it doesnt get loaded until triggered.

Comment: Ive got it. [See this working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HfwWY/2566/) for an example solution. Thanks for all your help, couldnt have done it without you!

Comment: Oh 200 yea then definitely don't hide it. You would need to bind the video handlers after the source changes which is what you have done in the fiddle